# How to search array for hotel room number then store a guest name to that room?

Tags: java, arrays

```
System.out.println("Please enter the number of the Basic room you would like to book : Basis Room 1, Basis Room 2, Basis Room 3 or Basic Room 4");
int  rooms = input.nextInt();
int Key = rooms;
for (int i = 0; i<basicRooms.length;i++){
if (Key ==(basicRooms[i])){
System.out.println("Basic room " + rooms + " is empty"); break;
```

Comment: use Map instead of aarray, assign guest name to that room

Comment: Not a Java guy, but you should use the `HashMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is sample code, which will store guest name with room number

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map <Integer, String> basicRooms =new HashMap <Integer,String>();
    basicRooms.put(1,"");
    basicRooms.put(2,"");
    basicRooms.put(3,"");
    basicRooms.put(4,"");
    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the Basic room you would like to book : Basis Room 1, Basis Room 2, Basis Room 3 or Basic Room 4");
        int  rooms = input.nextInt();
        int key = rooms;

        for (int i = 0; i<=basicRooms.size();i++){

            if (basicRooms.containsKey(key) ){
        System.out.println("Basic room " + rooms + " is empty");
        System.out.println("Please enter Guest name");
        input.nextLine();
        String  guestName = input.nextLine();

        basicRooms.put(key, guestName);
        break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Empty");

        }
        }
        System.out.println(basicRooms);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think you should use HashMap.Room as key and name as value.If u want to show Room according to insertion order,you can use LinkedHashMap.Including guestName attribute in Room class is code smell,because guestName in Room will be set if the room has registered Guest.If there is no guest registered for That Room,the attribute guestName will not be setted and it will be extra code.It is code smell.

Answer (score -1):

Use hashmap. Room as key and name as value.